# Bootstrap dropdown menu bad styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with styling a dropdown-menu in my website. When I open and close the menu and go away with mouse from the button, the button has bad style. I searched all over the internet, but did not find a solution.

Normal page look like this:

[image: Normal page]

After double-click on button and go away with mouse page look like this:

[image: Page after double-click on button]

I mean, this will repair some class in CSS, but I dont know which.

Thanks for answer and sorry for my English. I am not from an English speaking country.

Comment: Please post the respective css and html structure here and create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) recreating your problem.

Comment: Hi. There is html, css on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y7NHj/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this CSS so it won't become white anymore

```
.nav > li > a:focus{
     background:transparent;   
}
```

Make sure you put it after the Bootstrap CSS